# all radio button suddenly unchecked when the recyclerview was scrolled (android kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, radio-button

i make dynamic radio button list inside each row in recyclerview but when i random scroll all radio button uncheked i use model to store radiobutton condition,notifyItemChanged,initialize first cheked,using layout instead radiogroup , and use selection condition to check spesific radiobutton, but i cant solve this problem

**following the first picture all radio button is checked**

[image]

**but when scrolling down and back up all radiobutton is not checked**

[image]

this my item layout inside recyclerview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayoutlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <LinearLayout

            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/questionText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Sumber Data" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout

            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/tidak_ada"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Tidak Ada" />


        </LinearLayout>

    </TableRow>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radiogroup"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical"></LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

my code to create radiobutton inside adapter in `onBindViewHolder`

```
var rprms = InputFieldHolder.radiogroup?.layoutParams
        if(rprms != null && question.pilihan_jawabans.count() > 0){
            InputFieldHolder.radiogroup?.removeAllViews()
            question.pilihan_jawabans.forEachIndexed {i,e->
                val rdbtn = RadioButton(context)
                rdbtn.id = question.pilihan_jawabans[i].id
                rdbtn.text = question.pilihan_jawabans[i].isi.toString()
                rprms = RadioGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
                InputFieldHolder.radiogroup?.addView(rdbtn, rprms)

                val size = InputFieldHolder.radiogroup?.childCount?.minus(1)

                if(question.pilihan_jawabans[i].checked){
                    for (x in 0..size!!) {
                        if((InputFieldHolder.radiogroup?.getChildAt(x) is RadioButton)){
                            if((InputFieldHolder.radiogroup?.getChildAt(x) as RadioButton).id != question.pilihan_jawabans[i].id){
                                (InputFieldHolder.radiogroup?.getChildAt(x) as RadioButton).setChecked(false)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                rdbtn.setChecked(question.pilihan_jawabans[i].checked)
                rdbtn.setTag(Integer(question.pilihan_jawabans[i].id))

                rdbtn.setOnCheckedChangeListener({ group, checked ->
                    question.pilihan_jawabans.forEachIndexed {ii,ee->
                        if(checked){
                            question.pilihan_jawabans[ii].checked = false
                        }
                    }
                    question.pilihan_jawabans[i].checked = checked
                    notifyItemChanged(position)
                })
            }


        }
```

my model to store radiobutton checked state

```
@Parcelize
class QuestionSelection(
    var id : Int,
    var isi : String,
    var keterangan : String,
    var checked : Boolean = false

) : Parcelable
```

**NOTE :** my radiobutton is dynamic so not just 2 option but more than it,depending on the data that I took from the API

Comment: yes if you look code above is inside onBindViewHolder i call it in `rdbtn.setChecked(question.pilihan_jawabans[i].checked)` and `question.pilihan_jawabans[i].checked` is data from my model and `checked` store true or false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after few hour to solve , i finally got what cause the problem.i always call `InputFieldHolder.radiogroup?.removeAllViews()` to destroy all radiobutton and make new with new satet but radio group always save state from previous radiobutton has been destroy so in last i just call `InputFieldHolder.radiogroup?.clearCheck()` after destroy radio button to clear all check state inside the radio group